# Windows in the same application won't group together in Gnome launcher

Tags: gnome, gnome3, konsole

I am using Kali Linux, which uses GNOME 3. I have installed Konsole and added Konsole to Favorites (the second icon from top). However, whenever I launch new window of Konsole, I get separate new icons in the launcher (2 Konsole windows - 2 icons in the bottom). I also cannot move these 2 icons around.

I want to make my Konsole windows to have the same behavior with the default Gnome Terminal (the 3rd icon from bottom) where 2 windows are grouped into the same icon. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I don't know why but renaming the `org.kde.konsole.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` into `konsole.desktop` does the trick

```
cd /usr/share/applications/
sudo mv org.kde.konsole.desktop konsole.desktop
```

Comment: That's pretty hackish if you ask me and this is actually a bug IMHO. The executable is called `konsole` (and not `org.kde.konsole`) and I think problem comes from the fact that the application is not setting its application name when starting, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationName-prop